# React-redux + React-native-local-mongodb

Tags: mongodb, reactjs, react-native, redux, react-redux

I am using react-native-local-mongodb in my app with react-redux. The database queries are slow which are loading data after the states updation.

I am using the `componentDidMount` to load parts of the database using Redux, but results are complicated. I can't replace states because the conditional block (if else) close before the replacement then it returns my data later.

On the Mainpage, `onLoadDatabase()` is getting called in   `componentDidMount` which is loading the reducers

```
componentDidMount() {
    console.log('1_componentDidMount');  
    this.props.onLoadDatabase();   
    console.log('8_state after loading db: '+this.props.list);
};
```

my function in reducers is:

```
case LOAD_DATABASE:{
                console.log('2');
                let trainingsArray=null;
                mioDB.count({},(err,count)=>{
                    console.log('3_count:'+count);                    

                    if(count>=2){//it can't loads the database if there are two elements
                        console.log('4');
                        mioDB.find({},(err,trainings)=>{
                            console.log('5: '+JSON.stringify(trainings));
                            trainingsArray=trainings;
                        });

                    }else{//it must loads the database
                        console.log('4');
                        mioDB.insert([training1,training2],function(err,trainings){
                            console.log('5_');

                            mioDB.find({},(err,trainings)=>{
                                console.log('5.1: '+JSON.stringify(trainings));
                                trainingsArray=trainings;
                            });
                        });
                    }
                    console.log('6');
                    console.log('7.1'+state);
                    Object.assign({},state,{list:trainingsArray});                   
                });
                console.log('7.2'+state);

                return Object.assign({},state,{list:trainingsArray});                
            }break;
```

Debugger output:

[image: Debugger]

Comment: Your DB queries have no place in your reducer. Reducers should be pure functions (no side effects, and predictability of the output for any given input). You should query your data in the *action* that dispatches the `LOAD_DATABASE` action type (say, `loadDatabase`), and pass that data as the action payload. Then your reducer can take that data and update the state accordingly. Note that you will need a package like redux-thunk to manage asynchronous queries in your action.

Comment: I'm having same problems in other app. I have add "appyMiddleware" and thunk (using react-thunk) in the configureStore.js file. But how I can import data from local database? I should call loadDB() method in the componentDidMount in the MainPage, then in the action function I call ".map" from the database, but the reducer doesn't receve data